# How to implement MS Graph Application Permissions in Blazor WASM?

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, blazor, blazor-webassembly, azure-ad-msal

I have a Blazor WASM app that's currently using Delegated permissions to authorize ursers for an API.

In addition to this I want to allow the app to access any users calendar (App permission: Calendars.ReadWrite) via MS Graph to be able to create calendar events for users in our Tenant.

I'm currently using MSAL for authenticating users and authorize them using claims.

My current implementation for getting the Graph client is written like this:

```
public GraphServiceClient GetGraphClient()
    {
        string[] scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default", "https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.ReadWrite" };
        var tenantId = _configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"];

        // Values from app registration
        var clientId = _configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
        var clientSecret = _configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"];

        var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
        };

        // https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential
        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
            tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

        //Throws an 'Operation not supported on this platform' exception
        return new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
    }
```

When the above method gets called, I get an `'Operation is not supported on this platform.'` exception when instantiating a new GraphServiceClient.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd say this library is not compatible with webassembly and you are going to have to add a server endpoint to handle this

Comment: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sample-blazor-clientside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a blazor webassembly stand-alone application, then you can't use [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to use the application permission to call graph api, this is designed for daemon application. You have to have a server.

> These types of applications are often referred to as daemons or
> service accounts

This is the test result with a blazor web assembly asp.net core hosted application and it worked well.

[image]

By the way, the scope for client credential flow should only be `/.default`.

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "aad_app_id";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var res = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
```

Comment: Hi, can you help me, please, what API permission is needed because my Blazor WASM client complains: Operation is not supported on this platform.

Comment: `Blazor WASM client` is a signal page application which can't use `https://graph.microsoft.com/.defaul` as the scope. your error doesn't mean you used incorrect api permission... I'm afraid you used `/.defaul` in your code

Comment: Ah, it means I must use another scope than  .default or SPA cannot call Graph API?

Comment: You had an SAP and your requirement is calling a Graph API. Then just like what we know, we need to get authorized first(to get the access token) then we can call graph api. To get authorized, azure ad provide 2 kinds of flows, one is user flow(using delegated api permission which requiring users to sign in first), another is application flow(for those application such as api app/daemon app which don't have a web page to let sign in) , for SPA, it only support user flow. Ok, now we need to pick up an authorize flow and the recommended one is auth code flow.

Comment: For different programing language there're differnt SDK, you used Blazor, so this is the [official sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-blazor-wasm/tree/main/WebApp-graph-user/Call-MSGraph). And another point we need to know is the `delegated api permission`, for example [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions), you can see the details, then we need to add api permissions in Azure portal, then the scope we used in the code should be `User.ReadBasic.All User.ReadWrite.All Directory.ReadWrite.All`

Comment: SPA can call MS graph api, but it can't use client credential flow, it can only use, for example auth code flow, then the api permission is different. so you can't use `/.default` in your code. for client credential flow the scope is `/.default`, for other flows, the scope is what you added in azure portal.